# How to compile gcc-4.0 on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, open-source, gcc

So far I've successfully launched the configure, but when I type make, I get the following error, after some time (there's a lot which compile successfully):

```
ld: unknown/unsupported architecture name for: -arch i686
/usr/bin/libtool: internal link edit command failed
make[2]: *** [libgcc_s.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libgcc.a] Error 2
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

Is there a way to tell gcc not to compile itself for the i686 architecture?

Here's my `uname -a` if it can help:

```
Darwin Frizlabs-Computer.local 12.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

PS: I know gcc-4.0 is ancient, but I do need it.

Comment: Wh do you need gcc 4.0, surely better to fix that reason, and perhaps easier

Comment: I want to compile SheepShaver, which is a complex project and only compiles (AFAIK) with gcc-4.0. Trust me, if I could avoid compiling gcc-4.0, I would!

Comment: The macports port of sheepshaver seems to use the standard Apple compiler and the [home page](http://sheepshaver.cebix.net/) seems to show no need for gcc 4.0 (+ there are binaries there)

Comment: Using the default compiler (clang) does not work **at all** (the compiler crashes while compiling! I've submitted a bug report to Apple). I've also tried compiling with gcc-4.2, using the same command lines/patches used in MacPorts. The program compiles but does not work. I read somewhere SheepShaver had to be compiled with gcc-4.0, that's why I'm trying to compile it first as its not available anywhere in binary form on Mountain Lion.

Comment: re binaries click on the binary links to http://www.emaculation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=7360&sid=f901ceca77d7cbf4884f7ef7dee9ffa1

Comment: I don't want the binary of SheepShaver, I want to compile it from scratch. I have to compile it to patch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone on serverfault answered [the same question](https://superuser.com/questions/498826/how-to-compile-gcc-4-0-on-mountain-lion). So here's the way to compile gcc-4.0 on OS X Mountain Lion (copied from serverfault):

First get the old 4.0 package that was included with XCode 3.1 from [Apple's Open Source page](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/developer-tools-314/)

Download the gcc-5493 package and build using:

```
mkdir darwin
cd darwin
../configure --prefix=/tmp/testplace --enable-languages=objc,c++
make bootstrap
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled the dev version from a git clone and it compiles with gcc 4.7.2